# How do I extend a Facebook user access token?

Tags: facebook

According to Facebook's documentation, the access token is good for 60 days after the user's most recent use of the app.

> When your app uses Facebook Login to authenticate someone, it receives
> a User access token. If your app uses one of the Facebook SDKs, this
> token lasts for about 60 days. However, the SDKs automatically refresh
> the token whenever the person uses your app, so the tokens expire 60
> days after last use. If your app doesn't use the Facebook SDKs, you
> need to include code that refreshes the User token manually. If the
> User access token expires, your app must put the user through the
> login flow again.

By using the debug_token endpoint, you can view the expiration date of the token's access to their API.

```
$response = file_get_contents_curl('https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token='. $this->access_token .'&access_token=' . $this->access_token);
```

This will return something like this:

```
string(1386) "{
   "data": {
      "app_id": "867-5309",
      "type": "USER",
      "application": "Jenny's Phone Number",
      "data_access_expires_at": 1603124081,
      "expires_at": 1600452140,
      "is_valid": true,
      "issued_at": 1595268140,
      ........etc.
```

However, when I run API calls, it does not change that number or extend it. So are there specific API calls that constitute the user making use of the app? Or rather, what meets that definition?

The goal here would then be to use an API call that meets this definition to make a non-important, silent, background call once a week or once a month simply to keep the access token alive. Is something like this possible?

Comment: The extension only happen automatically in the mobile SDKs because there you are sure that the user is actually using the app. There is no way in the server SDKs to say that the user is doing something because that may not be true.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: So then is there a client side request where I can do the same thing? The app I'm talking about, I do have the user actively using it. So is there a JavaScript call that I can make that would be able to verify that it's from the user and accomplish the same thing?

Comment: No there is not.